# Не могу вставить ссылку в кнопку WP

Tags: php, wordpress

Страница содержит код:

```
> [column width="8" width_sm="12" css="padding: 0 20px"] [text_group
> header="ффф" image="http://www.40.png" image_position="top"
> header_css="margin-bottom: -10px; line-height: 28px"
> image_css="margin: 20px 0;" header_tag="h5"] <p>  <li>т </li>     <li>м
> </li>     <li>5</li>  <li>в</li>
> 
> </p> [button button_css="margin-top: 10px"]Read more[/button]
> [/text_group] [/column]
```

В кнопку `Read more` необходимо вставить ссылку. Пробовал всяко-разно средствами *HTML*.

Не получается, либо не работает, или ломает кнопку. Хотя кнопка активна и ведет на главную.

Вот что выводит браузер:

```
<div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12">
<div class="bd-layoutcolumn-shortcode" style="padding: 0 20px">
<div class="bd-vertical-align-wrapper">
<div class="media"><a href=""><img class="bd-imagestyles media-object img-responsive" style="margin: 20px 0;" src="http://www.crimeasvetodiod.ru/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/altay701.png"/></a><div class="media-body"><h5 class="media-heading" style="margin-bottom: -10px; line-height: 28px">

0</h5></p>
<p>
<li>Потребляемая мощность : т </li>
<li>Световой поток : м </li>
<li>Исполнение : 5</li>
<li>Срок службы : в</li>
<p><a class="bd-button" href="/">Read more</a><br />
</div></div>
</p></div>
</div>
</div>
```

По всем *CSS* файлам пытался найти `class="bd-button"` и все, что нашел вот:

```
.bd-button-10 a {
  line-height: 20.00000001px;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.bd-container-43:not(.shape-only) button,
.bd-container-43:not(.shape-only) input[type="submit"],
.bd-container-43:not(.shape-only) input[type="button"],
.bd-container-43:not(.shape-only) a.bd-button-10[href],
.bd-container-43:not(.shape-only) .bd-button-10,
button.bd-button-10,
input.bd-button-10,
a.bd-button-10[href],
.bd-button-10 {
  /* default transparent bg otherwise you get gray default bg */
  background-color: transparent;
}
.bd-container-43:not(.shape-only) button,
.bd-container-43:not(.shape-only) input[type="submit"],
.bd-container-43:not(.shape-only) input[type="button"],
.bd-container-43:not(.shape-only) a.bd-button-10[href],
.bd-container-43:not(.shape-only) .bd-button-10,
button.bd-button-10,
input.bd-button-10,
a.bd-button-10[href],
.bd-button-10,
.bd-container-43:not(.shape-only) button:link,
.bd-container-43:not(.shape-only) input[type="submit"]:link,
.bd-container-43:not(.shape-only) input[type="button"]:link,
.bd-container-43:not(.shape-only) a.bd-button-10[href]:link,
.bd-container-43:not(.shape-only) .bd-button-10:link,
button.bd-button-10:link,
input.bd-button-10:link,
a.bd-button-10[href]:link,
.bd-button-10:link,
.bd-container-43:not(.shape-only) button:visited,
.bd-container-43:not(.shape-only) input[type="submit"]:visited,
.bd-container-43:not(.shape-only) input[type="button"]:visited,
.bd-container-43:not(.shape-only) a.bd-button-10[href]:visited,
.bd-container-43:not(.shape-only) .bd-button-10:visited,
button.bd-button-10:visited,
input.bd-button-10:visited,
a.bd-button-10[href]:visited,
.bd-button-10:visited {
  /* reset browser styles */
  border-width: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #269ccb;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 7px 15px;
  border: 0px solid #ffffff;
  background-image: none;
```

Направьте на путь правильный. Устал уже искать, как сделать такую не сложную операцию.

**UPD:**
  нашел в shotcode вот это:

```
// Button
public static function button($atts, $content='') {
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'link' => '/',
        'type' => 'default',
        'style' => '',
        'size' => '',
        'icon' => ''
    ), $atts));

    $classNames = 'bd-button';
    $linkContent = $content;
    $styles = array('default' => 'btn-default', 'primary' => 'btn-primary', 'success' => 'btn-success',
        'info' => 'btn-info', 'warning' => 'btn-warning', 'danger' => 'btn-danger', 'link' => 'btn-link');
    $sizes = array('large' => 'btn-lg', 'small' => 'btn-sm', 'xsmall' => 'btn-xs');

    if ($type === 'bootstrap') {
        $classNames = 'btn';
        array_key_exists(strtolower($style), $styles) ? $classNames .= ' ' . $styles[strtolower($style)] : '';
        array_key_exists(strtolower($size), $sizes) ? $classNames .= ' ' . $sizes[strtolower($size)] : '';
    }

    if ($icon !== '') {
        $linkContent = '<span class="' . esc_attr($icon) . '">&nbsp;</span>' . $linkContent;
    }

    return '<a class="' . $classNames . '" href="' . esc_attr($link) . '">' . $linkContent . '</a>';
```

Что тут использовать для вставки ссылки ?

Comment: Может, стоит попробовать что-то в духе `[button url="http://yourlink"][/button]`? Сужу по тому, что в выводе у вас ссылка на главную страницу - `<a class="bd-button" href="/">Read more</a>`, то есть на /. Очевидно, что вы используете какие-то shortcodes, но часто в разных темах они свои. Так что загляните лучше в руководство к теме, через какой параметр вам нужно передавать ссылку в shotcode [button].

Comment: @ilyinilyas Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваши комментарии в виде ответа.

Comment: [button url="http://yourlink"][/button] не работает

Answer (score 1):

Вам стоит попробовать что-то в духе `[button url="http://yourlink"][/button]`.

Сужу по тому, что в выводе у вас ссылка на главную страницу - 
`<a class="bd-button" href="/">Read more</a>`, то есть на /.

Очевидно, что вы используете какой-то shortcode, но часто в разных темах они свои. Так что загляните лучше в руководство к теме WordPress, через какой параметр вам нужно передавать ссылку в shotcode [button].

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте

```
[button link="http://yourlink"][/button]
```

А стиль, судя по коду, нужно задавать не через button_css, а через style. Получится:

```
[button link="http://yourlink" style="margin-top: 10px"]Read more[/button]
```